# How to change default editor in Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I'd like to be able to automatically open text files in my editor of choice from within flash builder when I right click, open with 'Default editor'.

Can't seem to find this in preferences. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the System's default editor for that file type.

Comment: thanks, but to be more accurate it's is the System Editor in FB, not System Default editor